# Jquery: why my 'find()' method not updating?

Tags: jquery

i have a function to find the length of finding class,  but it not working always return the length is '0';

some thing is wrong with my code: can any one advice me the proper way. but i need to use the same structure of the code style to achieve this.

look on to my code :

```
<div id='list'>
  <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>      
  </ul>
    <p></p>
</div>​

function callMe(params){
    $(params.list).click(function(){
       $(this).addClass('c_on');
        var length = $(params.list).find('.c_on').length;
        $('p').text(length)// return always 0, even i clicked no.of list.        
    })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var obj = {
        list : $('ul').find('li')      
    }
   callMe(obj);
})

style :

li.c_on{
border:1px solid green;
}
```

​
​Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AeGvf/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

when you should be using [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

Note that `find` works on the *descendants* whereas `filter` works on the elements themselves. You have a list of `<li>`s that don't have any descendants so `find` is searching an empty set. You should do this:

```
var length = $(params.list).filter('.c_on').length;
```

Also, your `params.list` is already a jQuery object so you don't need to `$(params.list)`, you can use `params.list` directly:

```
function callMe(params){
    params.list.click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('c_on');
        var length = params.list.filter('.c_on').length;
        $('p').text(length);
    });
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/uCGaY/

Answer (score 0):

Your selection method is bit flawed. Use this one instead:

```
function callMe(params){
    params.list.click(function(){
       $(this).addClass('c_on');
        var length = $(this).parent().find('.c_on').length;
        $('p').text(length)        
    })
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AeGvf/2/)

Comment: that's what i said, i am not always find the parent length, some time i may need the length from no.of UL's from the section.

Comment: @3gwebtrain, You are not finding the parent's length. You are finding the child `.c_on` elements of the parent selector.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution work fine :

```
function callMe(params){
    $(params.list).click(function(){
       $(this).addClass('c_on');
        var length = $(params.list).filter('.c_on').length;//instead find i used filter. works!
        $('p').text(length)        
    })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var obj = {
        list : $('ul').find('li')      
    }
   callMe(obj);
})
​
```

But till i am wondering why the find method is not work? or is there any constrain to use that? or the way i did is wrong..? please answer me any one finds.

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me. I have modified the names but you were calling to find the class elements inside the same element, not the parent.

```
<script>
    function callMe(params) {

        $(params).click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('c_on');
            var suspects = $("#list").find('.c_on');

            $('p').text(suspects.length); // return always 0, even i clicked no.of list.        
        });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    var obj = $('li');

    callMe(obj);
})
</script>
```